# Is there any way to connecto multiple request/trigger form SQS to single thread lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My app is using lambda function (1) to import data to a third database server. Sometime (1) will throw errors, and I use SQS to store messages throw from (1). And I use lambda function (2) to read all messages in SQS and re-import by recall (1). (2) will triggered whenever SQS receives the message.

Full error flow: Lambda (1) => SQS => Lambda (2) => Lambda (1).

The problem is, if DB server is maintained, it will be infinite loop until DB server active again.

My solution is, create a lambda function (3) doing like a flag, checks DB server status. It will run when SQS receives new message, run repeatedly until DB server active again. This time Lambda (2) is called.

And I want this Lambda (3) is a single thread (singleton ?), all request from SQS are in one thread.

=> With this solution, system only need retry one thread if DB server down.

New flow: Lambda (1) => SQS => Single thread Lambda (3) => Lambda (2) => Lambda (1)

My question is:

1. My solution is possible or not?
2. If it's possible then how to setup Lambda (3) ?
3. If it's impossilbe then is there any way to do resolve my problem?
   Please help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using throttling and CloudWatch scheduled event triggers.

You can set up CloudWatch scheduled event to periodically run lambda function 3 (the one responsible for DB status checking). I am not sure what you mean by single threaded but I guess that you mean that at most one instance of that function will be run simultaneously. This is easy because CloudWatch scheduled event will run that function just once per *x - amount of time* which you can specify.

Once the above function (3) detects that the DB is unhealthy, it can set concurrency limit on you lambda function that reads messages from SQS (2) and throttle it down to 0 so that lambda function (2) cannot be executed at all.

When the function (3) detects that the DB is healthy, it will remove this concurrency limit from function (2).

So the code of the lambda function (3) could look something like this

```
if db_is_not_healthy:
    lambda.put_function_concurrency(
        FunctionName=function_2,
        ReservedConcurrentExecutions=0
    )
else:
    lambda.delete_function_concurrency(
        FunctionName=function_2
    )
```

How exactly you are going to setup your lambda health checks, when to start them, when to stop them, how often to ping the DB depends on your particular use case and how much you are willing to pay for it.

For example, you could start pinging the DB only after there are some errors with it. Once the lambda function (1) receives error response, it can then enable health checks - lambda (3) by unthrottling it and once lambda (3) decides that DB is healthy again, it can throttle itself so that this health checks are performed only when there are problems with the DB.

This is definitely not the most elegant solution but it should work after some tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try this.